# Error with download a file from https using webclient

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, https, webclient

I have create a piece of code that download a file from a given URL using WebClient.

The problem is i am getting the following error when the code is trying to download a file from a `HTTPS` site.

```
The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure
```

This issue happened only on the server not on the local machine, so i also don't know how to debug it.

I have read several answers on the web but didn't find anything that could help me.

The piece of code:

```
 using (WebClient Client = new WebClient())
        {
            string fileName = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["siteUploadedDirectory"] 
            + "/temp/" + Context.Timestamp.Ticks.ToString() 
            + "_" + FileURL.Substring(FileURL.LastIndexOf('/')+1);
            fileName = Server.MapPath(fileName);
            Client.DownloadFile(FileURL, fileName);
            return fileName + "|" + FileURL.Substring(FileURL.LastIndexOf('/')+1);
        }
```

The URL i am trying:

```
http://Otakim.co.il/printreferrer.aspx?ReferrerBaseURL=cloudents.com
&ReferrerUserName=ram
&ReferrerUserToken=1
&FileURL=https://www.cloudents.com/d/lzodJqaBYHu/pD0nrbAtHSq
```

The file URL:
FileURL=https://www.cloudents.com/d/lzodJqaBYHu/pD0nrbAtHSq

Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can bypass the certificate validation process by following code snieppet

```
    ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback
 += (sender, certificate, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true;
```

Comment: where are you using this lambda expression

Comment: Just before the "string filename =" line

Comment: This is the full method definition in VB if you don't like Lambda expressions in your code
```Public Shared Function ServerCertificateValidationCallback(sender As Object, cert As System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate, chain As System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Chain, optional_item As Object) As Boolean
    Return True
End Function```